# How to prevent third-party (e.g. client) from copying or changing the code after it has deployed on client on-premise Server?

Tags: node.js, angular, server, web-deployment

The problem is, I need to deploy my application on the client's on-premise Server. So is there any way or encryption through which I can prevent my code to be copied by the client?

Technology I am using for my application 

frontend: Angular 

Backend : Nodejs